# Update phonegap cordova version

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to update the latest cordova version to my project. I did run the below command:

```
  $ sudo npm update -g cordova
```

after running this command, I checked and using cordova info command I can see that I have the latest version of cordova

```
Node version: v0.12.2

Cordova version: 5.3.1

Config.xml file:
```

However, when I go to the platform folder and ran

```
cordova platform version ios
```

The results is showing that I am still in the older version.

```
Installed platforms: ios 3.9.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, android, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, osx, webos
```

I tried using the cordova platform update but I am getting an error, see below. Am I missing anything?

```
cordova platform update ios@5.3.1
Failed to fetch platform ios@5.3.1
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: version not found: cordova-ios@5.3.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various parts or cordova (cli, platforms, plugins) all move and release independently, which means they all can and will have different version numbers. For example the current release of the cordova-ios platform is 3.9.1 and the current release of android is 4.1.1. You can see what platforms are available by running

```
cordova platform list
```

You can see all published versions for a given platform via npm

```
npm view cordova-{platform} versions
```

replacing {platform} with anything given by the `list` command above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I found this documentation too http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/